# mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (64x1 and 512x64)

Tags: python, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I have this code, I try to add the second layer GAT. But when I do it I have `mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (64x1 and 512x64)` for two GAT. But when I have one GAT everything is ok.

```
class AntispoofModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, device="cpu", **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        resnet = torch.hub.load('pytorch/vision:v0.10.0', 'resnet18', pretrained=True)
        self.resnet = nn.Sequential(*[i for i in list(resnet.children())[:-2]]).to(device)
        for ch in self.resnet.children():
            for param in ch.parameters():
                param.requires_grad = False
        self.gat = GAT(**kwargs).to(device)
        self.device = device
        self.adj = torch.tensor(grid_to_graph(3, 3, return_as=np.ndarray)).to(device)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.resnet(x.to(self.device))
        x = nn.functional.avg_pool2d(x, 2)
        x = x.view(-1, 9, 512)
        x = self.gat(x, self.adj)
        x = self.gat(x, self.adj)
        return torch.sigmoid(x)
```

I understand that matrix should be like `(m x n) with (n x p)`. But I don't understand where I should change my code. I try to change:

```
    transforms.Resize(256),
    transforms.CenterCrop(224),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
])

torch.manual_seed(42)
kwargs = {"nfeat":512, "nhid":64, "nclass":1, "nheads":9, "dropout":0.6, "alpha":0.01}

train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)
test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)
```

But it doesn't give result. Values of matrix changes only.
Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: You could transpose both `mat1` and `mat2`. While this would formally work, you should probably ask yourself if that is what you need at the end of the computation.

Comment: Thanks! As I understood I should ```torch.transpose```. But I don't understand where I need to use it for my code at all...

Comment: I use this [GAT](https://github.com/Diego999/pyGAT/blob/master/layers.py). Here I have mistake in 27 line where ```Wh = torch.mm(h, self.W)```

Comment: From the naming, it looks like you are computing `hW` instead. I'd try to use: `Wh = torch.mm(self.W, h)`

Comment: Then I have ```mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (32768x9 and 64x512)```. I also use ```mutmul``` instead of ```mm```